# Вызов яндекс такси из стороннего приложения (android)

Tags: java, android-intent, яндекс-такси

Вызов яндекс навигатора:

```java
Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.format("yandexnavi://build_route_on_map?lat_to=%1$f&lon_to=%2$f", lat, lon).replace(',', '.'));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Вызов яндекс такси:

```java
String value = "https://3.redirect.appmetrica.yandex.com/route?";
String route = String.format("end-lat=%1$f&end-lon=%2$f&ref=stroyparksu&appmetrica_tracking_id=1178268795219780156", lat, lon).replace(',', '.');
Uri uri = Uri.parse(value + route);

Intent browse = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(browse);
```

Во втором случае открывается броузер а потом уже приложение. Есть ли возможность загрузки приложения сразу, по аналогии с картами и навигатором? В документации не нашел никакой информации.

Comment: Вызов напрямую приложения через yandextaxi://route?